# Can Mule Expression Language (MEL) be used outside of the MuleESB?

Tags: mule-el

I need to use an expression language and there are many to choose from.  MEL has stood out as very easy to understand and powerful.  However, Mule Expression Language is in the mule core library in maven.

Can MEL work as a *standalone* expression language outside of the MuleESB like Spring Expression Language, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

No. MEL is only implemented in Mule ESB/Runtime. Note that it has been deprecated by [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule4-user-guide/v/4.1/dataweave) since Mule 3.7.